# problemas com inicialização em modo gráfico

Tags: linux, fortran

Eu coloquei o endereço do compilador do Fortran (ifort) no `.bashrc` fazendo:

```
export PATH=/.../...
```

Mas após isso não consegui acessar o modo gráfico do OpenSuse. A mensagem dada é a seguinte:

> Could not connect to session bus dbus-lauch terminated abnormally without any error messeger on opensuse.

Gostaria de idéias para que eu possa resolver este problema

Comment: Parece que você sobrescreveu ou editou o PATH antigo e o problema pode ser por isso.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Tente fazer desta forma:

PATH="**$PATH:**/caminho/bin/:/outro_caminho/bin/"

É importante que a variável $PATH anterior seja concatenada com as novas definições, que os caminhos sejam separados por dois pontos e que não haja espaços antes e depois do '='.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, tenta tirar o que você adicionou (apaga a linha que define a variável PATH no .bashrc) para recuperar o teu modo gráfico.
Depois disso, a edição da variável PATH tem que ser feita do jeito que @vrcca falou:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/caminho/do/compilador/fortran"
```